# datetime format inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here is the problem I have.

I have datetime as a row in database,how do I configure php so it inserts the correct datetime into the database from the php script I can only seem to work with vanchar(255) at the moment.

Comment: //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Cars` VALUES ('', 'Pending', '$price', '{$fetchAccount['email']}', '".time()."', '$content', '$description', '$area', '$town', '$UK', '$target', '0')") ;

Comment: @user1722740 why not post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's date/time formats are `yyyy-mm-dd mm:hh:ss`. If you insert time and/or date values in any other format, they're likely to get trashed and set to the default values. You can use functions like [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert a non-conforming string to native MySQL values if need be.

Comment: Yh thats what happens just sets date to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: so yes, you're inserting some non-recognizable date and mysql's using the default all-zeroes version to save it. you HAVE to use mysql's native format, or convert to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
function format_mysql_datetime($raw) {
        $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';
        $stringtime =  strtotime($raw);
        return strftime($format, $stringtime);  
}

$raw = date('c');

$sql='insert into myTable (theDateTimeField)
values ('.format_mysql_datetime($raw).')';
mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

This works if you use date('c') instead of time().  Make sure you set your default timezone or it might display the wrong time.  See [date_default_timezone_set.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Note that you should not be using mysql_*. Instead, use PDO. Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, which you have to guard against anytime you use external input in a query. I didn't write my answer using PDO because I wanted to emphasize how to handle the date and not confuse you with introducing another new concept.

Also check out these docs:

- [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)
- [DateTime format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: That works thank you just need to figure out how you do timezone as date is right but time is wrong,I am new to all this kinda stuff so am a bit noobish at certain things.

Comment: Just want it to show in one format gmt

Comment: That I don't know.  Take a look at the supported timezones here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php.  GMT is under other, but it is depreciated.  I don't know what city you would pick - but I do know cities in Iceland use GMT year round.

Comment: Another option you have is to set the timezone mysql uses and use now() - which is a mysql function not php.  So...$sql='insert into myTable(theDateTimeField) values (now())';